# Django - Cycle Tag. How can I make it work?

Tags: python, django, templating

I am a total newbie to Django. I am trying to implement cycle tag. To no avail.
My view.py:

```
def music(request):
    my_list = ['Ravel', 'Bach', 'Verdi', 'Janacek']
    context ={'my_list': my_list}
    return render(request, 'music.html', context)
```

My template file:

```
<head>
<style>
   .row1 {
         background: #FFFF00;
     }
   .row2 {
         background: #FF0000;
    }
</style>

<h1>Music</h1>

</head>
 <body>
{% for o in my_list %}<tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}"></tr>{% endfor %}
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a question about Django or the cycle tag.

You need to put something inside the table row for it to show in HTML. A `tr` needs to contain one or more `td`s, and in turn the `td` needs to contain some actual text. Also ,the whole thing needs to be inside a `<table>`.

```
<table>
{% for o in my_list %}
    <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
        <td>{{ o }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! It appears I am going to have to do a bit of reading on...HTML.

Comment: perhaps my td's just aren't getting generated and i am wrongly suspecting this cycle line